# reducing my amps

Tags: power-supply

I have a line running 240v and 100 Amps. i would like to tap into that line at various points, to install equipment, without having to run a separate line back to the panel and a separate circuit breaker, due to the distance and the number of machines to install.
So, is there any small device transformer, or regulator, or variable resistor, to install just before my machines , that will take in 110A 240V and provide 35A, 240V output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: 100A will be the *maximum* capacity.

Comment: If you have to ask this question then you are not qualified to tamper with 240V 100A installations.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want something which will allow you to connect to a 100 A circuit, and allow a draw of 135 amps without popping the circuit breaker, right? I suggest you study magic.

Answer (score 4):

Get an electrician or other qualified individual to do it.